# Relative distance metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean norm.

Let $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x \neq 0$ and $||v|| = 1$.

Is it possible to define a (possibly infinite) metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies
$$  \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{d(x+hv, x)}{h} = \frac{1}{||x||}$$
and
$$ d(x, y) = d(\alpha x, \alpha y)$$
for $\alpha > 0$.

Context: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/intuition-for-relative-error-for-vectors

Comment: Are you only wanting $$\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{d(x+hv, x)}{h} = \frac{1}{||x||}$$ and $$d(x,y) = d(\alpha x, \alpha y)$$ to be for the particular $x$ you fixed at the beginning?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: for all $x, v, y$ ideally